# How do I tell what my make and model of my computer is?

Tags: linux

Is there a way of finding out what the make and model of computer is without simply going to the box or looking at the label on the computer if it had one?

For example if my computer was a HP Pavilion 17-f000 Notebook PC series and I wanted to find that out by using a CLI or GUI program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command line:

`sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name` **or** `sudo dmidecode --string system-product-name`

**Alternatively**

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -A3 '^System Information'
```

---

`dmidecode` provides a description of the computer's hardware information.

The `-s` `--string` flag with the DMI string `system-product-name`, only outputs the make and model of your computer.

`| grep` pipes the output to grep and the `-A3` flag for grep prints 3 lines after a match for System Information.

Comment: @marhki That would work if the period at the end wasn't there. Also you only need four spaces to format code-blocks on stackexchange.

Comment: The `.` was a period to end the sentence. I've amended the response for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `dmidecode` command-line program, one can find the exact model of anything in your PC. Getting the make and model of your computer can be done with the `-s, --string` flag with the DMI string `system-product-name`:

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
```

Comment: I tried this command on Debian 7, Ubuntu 14.04, and CentOS 7 without success. I've proposed an alternative answer using dmidecode.

Comment: @marshki what version of dmidecode are you using? I have v2.12. Also if you run `dmidecode -s` without any keywords, does it have "system-product-name" listed as valid keywords?

Comment: v.2.12 on all tested machines. "System-product-name" appears as a valid keyword in each case.

Comment: @marshki If it does, then the `dmidecode -s system-product-name` or `dmidecode --string system-product-name` should work.